# How to use Scaffold-DbContext in .NET Core for SQL Server Compact (*.sdf File) database

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, sql-server-ce, sdf

I'm using .NET Core Version 7 and I want to use EF Core to access a SQL Server Compact (`*.sdf`) database file. What libraries to use and how to use `Scaffold-DbContext` to build the existing database models and also the database has a password.

**I want to use database first method.**
I added this library to the project:

```
[ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact or EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerCompact40] ,
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

**If the problem is with the `provider`, what library should be added to the project and what `provider` should be written?**

I have **Sql Server Compact** and **SQLite/Sql Server Compact Toolbox** installed,
But when I run `Scaffold-DbContext` as follows, it gives this error:

```
 Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=Path\db.sdf;Password=***" -provider
 [ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact or
EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerCompact40] ...
```

[image]

**Error Text When I am using ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact library::**

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find expected assembly
> attribute [DesignTimeProviderServices] in provider assembly
> 'ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact'. This attribute is required
> to identify the class which acts as the design-time service provider
> factory for the provider.    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.ConfigureProviderServices(String
> provider, IServiceCollection services, Boolean throwOnError)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.CreateServiceCollection(String
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.Build(String
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String
> provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String
> outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace,
> Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean
> useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluralize)
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String
> provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String
> outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, String modelNamespace,
> String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean
> overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean
> suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluralize)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
> action) Unable to find expected assembly attribute
> [DesignTimeProviderServices] in provider assembly
> 'ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact'. This attribute is required
> to identify the class which acts as the design-time service provider
> factory for the provider.

**Error Text When I am using EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerCompact40 library:**

> System.TypeLoadException: Method 'Create' in type
> 'EFCore.SqlCe.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlCeDatabaseModelFactory' from
> assembly 'EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerCompact40, Version=2.2.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9af395b34ac99006' does not have an
> implementation.    at
> EFCore.SqlCe.Design.Internal.SqlCeDesignTimeServices.ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection
> serviceCollection)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.ConfigureDesignTimeServices(Type
> designTimeServicesType, IServiceCollection services)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.ConfigureProviderServices(String
> provider, IServiceCollection services, Boolean throwOnError)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.CreateServiceCollection(String
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.Build(String
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String
> provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String
> outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace,
> Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean
> useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluralize)
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String
> provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String
> outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, String modelNamespace,
> String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean
> overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean
> suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluralize)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
> action) Method 'Create' in type
> 'EFCore.SqlCe.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlCeDatabaseModelFactory' from
> assembly 'EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerCompact40, Version=2.2.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9af395b34ac99006' does not have an
> implementation.

Comment: SQL Server CE is out of support. Why are you using it, and where will you find the binaries? You realize that *you* will be responsible for any bugs in the product if you use it?

Comment: While SQL Server CE was still supported, @ErikEJ maintained the [EF provider for SQL Server CE](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact). This only targets on .NET Framework because SQL Server CE itself only run on Windows. The NuGet package is still available but no longer maintained

Comment: Why not target SQLite instead? EF Core already supports SQLite - in fact the provider was built and maintained by ErikeEJ too. It was so good it was eventually incorporated into EF Core itself. There *are* some significant differences compared to CE, especially around concurrent access and transaction behavior, but CE is already unsupported

Comment: What's your actual scenario? There may be another MS product that fits, although it would almost certainly involve an Azure subscription.

Comment: I want to store my data in a resource that requires the least amount of external programs to install the program on the user's computer, and its volume is small, and the speed of reading and writing on that resource is average, that's why I want to use SQL Server CE. If there is something else, please suggest and tell how to use it. I want the information to be on the user's computer, not via Azure. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Why not SQLite? I repeat, SQL Server Compact is out of support. The last release was 10 years ago, so that was more than enough time for people to migrate away from it. You had to install it separately too - either directly, or through a Windows Installer merge module. The engine was never included in .NET itself

Comment: And likewise, if there is another library, a side program that must be installed on the user's computer, tell me. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: On the other hand, the SQLite engine is just a library. When you add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` to your package, a [SQLite library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3/) is added to the project. Nothing else has to be installed

Comment: You can use an example of `Scaffold-DbContext` where the desired sqlite database file has a password. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: I asked another question and explained all the problems there: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77024042/how-to-use-scaffold-dbcontext-in-net-core-for-sqlite-database @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: I have a EF C´6 Classic prodvider for SQL Server Compact, I suggest you use that: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact/6.4.0-beta4

Comment: And SQL Server Compact supports a database password, correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a [EF 6 Classic prodvider for SQL Server Compact](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact/) - I suggest you use that.

The final version of the package will be released when I have gotten feedback from users that it works as expected.

You can view the package in NuGet UI in Visual Studio if you select "Include prerelease".

You can use the package with the EF 6 Database First toling if you install the SQL Server Compact runtime and the SQLite / SQL Server Compact Tools extension.

There is no EF Core .NET 7 provider for SQL Server Compact.

Comment: Can you tell me when the final version will be released?

Comment: If you have given the post -1, please remove it because it has not yet been published to the library officially and I did not see it in nuget either.

Comment: How can this library be used by the Database First method?

Comment: @MohammadHasanSalmanian I have updated my reply and I did not downvote your question,

Comment: It gives an error, is there a problem somewhere?

Comment: If you encounter any issues, please report them with full repro details in the GitHub repository